# CSS Animation With Delay Start And Initial Visibility

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to understand on how to have a first frame of a sprite sheet be hidden for a few seconds, then suddenly appear without a fade, and then proceed with the other frames.

Currently my code displays the first frame for 3 seconds, then it is hidden, and then proceeds with the other frames. What I want it to do is hide the first frame for 3 seconds, have it suddenly appear, and then proceed with the other frames.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

HTML

```
<div class="santa">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.santa {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background:  url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/183204/char.png') no-repeat 0 0%;
  animation: walk 7s steps(16) infinite 3s;
}

@keyframes walk {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
     visibility: visible;
         background-position: -2400px;
         transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/markerpower/pen/VwNvrmm

**Edit**

What ended up working:

CSS

```
.santa {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background:  url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/183204/char.png') no-repeat 0 0%;
  animation: walk 7s steps(16) infinite 3s;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes walk {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
     visibility: visible;
         background-position: -2400px;
         transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
}
```

Comment: The 0% means, it's going to start with visibility hidden but the walk property is delayed already by 3s, meaning it's not applying that.

You need to hide first the animation `visibility: hidden` then just show it up with `visibility: visible` on 0% because now is running the animation and considering your character.

Animations getting delayed does nothing until the animation properties are required, so you need to set all the properties to be required first then the animation ones